# Lookup Contact Data and show Content Block by Id only if value is true

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I am new to Salesforce and AMPscript and I am trying to set a condition to populate `%%=v(@BodyContent)=%%` with contact data (not journey data, therefore, I will need to use the Lookup) with a content block by id if the contact data attribute value returns true. If the value returns false or null I want to hide `%%=v(@BodyContent)=%%`.

Comment: here is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SFSE. Lets get you hooked up with some good Ampscript reference links to start out with:

- [SF Ampscript syntax guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/syntaxGuide.htm)
- [SF Ampscript function reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm)
- [Ampscript guide](https://ampscript.guide/)

What you need is to use a [lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) function as well as an [IF statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm#using-the-if-condition-evaluation), similar to as you described.

```
%%[
    /* Retrieve the identifier for your record in order to use in the lookup function */
    SET @id = AttributeValue('Id')

    /* Lookup the MyBooleanField field in your data extension. */
    SET @myField = Lookup('MyDataExtensionName','MyBooleanField','Id',@id)

    /* If the field is true then output the body content */
    IF @myField == 'True' THEN
]%%

<p>
    %%=v(@BodyContent)=%%
</p>

%%[
    ENDIF
]%%
```